# Can we make a POST request without using AJAX and without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms, http

Actually, I have to send a huge array of jsons to download a file. If we can do that, we can have huge array of jsons in request body.

I know 2 ways so far:
1. Using simple form submit POST request, which reloads page.
2. Using AJAX POST request, which makes us to hold whole file bytes formatted data from response.data at client side and then, save the file using BLOB, etc from third party js frameworks.

I have another approach, which can send huge json array in GET request using anchor tag or window.location. Is it reliable? where huge json array is appended to GET request URL. How much data, can URL hold?

Hope someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't send huge amounts in a GET request, don't rely on that.

Comment: GET/POST/PUT/DELETE etc ... they're all AJAX, the method doesn't change what it is :p

Comment: Thank you all for corrections/suggestions.